# Javascript not placing code in ID div

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I recently posted about a beginners issue in Javascript where I was writing a program to paste the text in an input form. Now I am trying to get the program to place the text in a specific div element so that the form does not disappear. I am new to this and do not know what I am doing wrong, so if you can help that would be great. The purpose of my program is supposed to be to write code for me based off an input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YAML Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="yamlform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="appname" value="Name">
      <button type="submit" onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="appnameSpace">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var appnamelocation = document.getElementById('appnameSpace')
    function writeAppName() {
      var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value
      document.getElementById(appnameSpace)
      document.write(appname)
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wouldn't php be better for this?

Comment: @SankarshMakam I don't know PHP so I just wrote it in what I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues. Specially using the form tag with a submit button, you will submit data to the server. No need of submit data in this case.
Here the final code.

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="appname" value="Name">
  <button onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
  <div id="appnameSpace">
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var appnamelocation = document.getElementById('appnameSpace');
function writeAppName() {
  var appname = document.getElementById('appname').value;
  var appnameSpaceElement = document.getElementById('appnameSpace');
  appnameSpaceElement.innerHTML = appname;
}
```

Here the working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/

Your final code should be the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YAML Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="appname" value="Name">
      <button onclick="writeAppName()">Submit</button>
      <div id="appnameSpace">
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var appnamelocation = document.getElementById('appnameSpace');
    function writeAppName() {
      var appname = document.getElementById('appname').value;
      var appnameSpaceElement = document.getElementById('appnameSpace');
      appnameSpaceElement.innerHTML = appname;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't publish my code -.-
btw if you copy and paste it in your example it should work

Comment: Click save in the navbar. (2nd from left not including home.)

Comment: yes I did :) thanks.
Posted your final code above in the answer, you can just copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeAppName() {
      var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value;
      document.getElementById('appnameSpace').innerHTML = '<h1>'+appname+'</h1>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YAML Generator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#appnameSpace").html($("#appname").val());
});
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="text" id="appname" name="appname" value="Name">
      <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
    <div id="appnameSpace">

    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not correct. You have a submit button within a form, which will trigger the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the document.write with appnamelocation.innerHTML:

appnamelocation.innerHTML =  appname

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to a `submit` event handler for the form so that the "enter" key can submit, too. Then you just need to reference your variables a little differently and use `innerHTML` instead of `document.write` to populate your div.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>YAML Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="yamlform" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return writeAppName()">
    <input type="text" name="appname" value="Name">
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div id="appnameSpace">

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function writeAppName() {
      var appname = document.getElementsByName("appname")[0].value,
        appnamelocation = document.getElementById("appnameSpace");
      appnamelocation.innerHTML = appname;
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```